# Trying to change out a radio button with a small image for selection of products

Tags: javascript, variables, button

I am trying to write some javascript that will pull information out of a page when it loads and replace the radio buttons with a small image instead of the button.  Also when the button is clicked on I need it to replace the large image on the screen.  Is this something that can be done with Javascript alone or do I need PHP?  I understand PHP but with the site I cant use it.  I am stuck.  I am happy to answer all questions about this.  I am kind of stuck.  Please help

Comment: Can you show us relevant parts of your current markup and code?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script I found to replace the radio buttons (and checkboxes and select dropdowns) with styling of your choice.

I recommend you read the short article before you jump into using it.

[ryanfait.com](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)

Also, the script for changing a larger image would be something **like**:

```
$('.radio').change(function(){
    $('#lgImg').src(newUrl);
});
```

Where `newUrl` would be based on some value of the radio button that was changed like: `$(this).attr('data-img-url')`

Finally, just as a side note, you wouldn't be able to do anything like this (client-side) in PHP unless you submitted the radio button on change (again, with Javascript) and reloaded the page with the correct larger image.  But that would be very dirty and fairly unnecessary.